# How goes Guest Access Point login screen redirect work?

Tags: wifi, access-point, guest

I have a guest AP that displays a login screen asking
for guest name and email when I connect to it via the 
Android Phone's wifi tab.
The login screen is opened after I have clicked on the
guest wifi, there is no password required, however you
need to insert your name and password and confirm to the
policy.
This has to be done every day, so I want to automate this
and use a RPI to do this. 
I'm starting wpa_supplicant to connect to the SSID but
now I wonder how I can get to the login screen url? If I have 
the URL I can automate the process via some browser testing
framework.

What type of mechanism is used to redirect to the guest 
login screen? Where does the login screen url come from (DHCP?)?
Is there a standard that is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The captive portal solution i know capture the first http request and redirect the browser to the login page. Firefox uses this URL to detect a captive portal: http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt

You can test this directly after your wifi connect with: curl -v http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt

You should see a 302 redirect.